# How to enable DataPipeline by scratch org definition file?

Tags: scratch-org, scratch-org-definition-file, feature-activation

[image]

I need to enable Data Pipelines in my Scratch Org automatically during creation. I couldn't find any option in documentation. Is there any option to autoenable it?